# How to drop DB2 Java Stored Procedure?

Tags: db2, java-stored-procedures

I have deployed a Java Stored Procedure through IBM Data Studio, and now I want to undeploy it, but I don't know how to do it completely.

I know you have to drop the procedure by calling `DROP PROCEDURE <procedure name>`.

Delete the record from `SYSIBM.SYSJAVAOPTS` that has my `JAR_ID`.

But how do you undeploy what `SQLJ.DB2_INSTALL_JAR` did?

It must have register my JAR file somewhere on DB2 because the first parameter is a `BLOB` of the JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `call sqlj.remove_jar( jar-id )` statement as described in [JAR file administration on the database server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/r0006425.html).